# How do I run an Android emulator automatically from Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I need to know how to run an Android emulator automatically from Eclipse.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 39):

Once you have installed [**ADT**](http://code.google.com/android/intro/installing.html#installingplugin), you need to define an [ADT launch configuration](http://code.google.com/android/intro/hello-android.html#run), in order for your project to execute itself as an Android executable.

[image: Hello World Android]

---

Then, do not forget to To go in `Eclipse->Preferences->Run/Debug->Launching`.
In the “`Launch Operation`” subsection, select “`Always launch the previously launched application`”:

[image: Eclipse launching options]

Comment: This caused so much pain, manually had to click "launch android application" every time...  Too bad it took me 6 months to even google the problem ;(

Comment: how did you make this second screen shot ?

Comment: @chiragsaga see the comments of http://stackoverflow.com/a/3590996/6309 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/2612688/6309 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/2306953/6309 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/3360636/6309 ... ;)

Comment: @chiragsaga: No. For Mac, I would go with http://www.flyingmeat.com/flysketch/ or (better) http://skitch.com/. Other alternatives listed at: http://alternativeto.net/software/faststone-capture/?platform=mac

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways for that..

- Launch *AVD* from **Menu bar**

  *Steps :*

  1. Click on **Android Virtual Device Manager**

     [image: image1]
  2. Select the device you have created and click **Start**

     [image: image2]
  3. Click **Launch** and wait to *AVD* be launched..

     [image: image3]
  4. Your *AVD* is running..

     [image: image4]
- Launch *AVD* from **Run Configuration**

  *Steps :*

  1. Right click on **Run** icon at menu bar and select *Run Configuration*

     [image: image5]
  2. Select **Target** tab > Select third radio option says *(Automatically pick compatible device : ...)* > Tick your desire *AVD* you want to launch > click **Apply** > click **Run**

     [image: image6]