# How can I install eclipse on Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: eclipse

Can anybody help me to install eclipse for windows 7 64 bit?
I have eclipse 64 bit and jdk 64 bit but it doesn't work?

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting? We need a little more info here...

Comment: For the record, just because you have a 64-bit machine does NOT mean you have to use 64-bit Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

I do run eclipse without any problem, with a JDK6-64 bit on a Windows 7
(use the "`Windows x64`" Platform option of the [Java SE download page](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/widget/jdk6.jsp)).

See my [**eclipse.ini** here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590).
If your 'java -version' displays something like:

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_18"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_18-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode)
```

, your eclipse should be able to launch itself without any problem.

[image: http://web.archive.org/web/20120916072909/http://img697.i_mageshack.us/img697/125/eclipseinstallationdeta.png]

Comment: my java version is also jdk1.6.0_18.
I think eclipse has some issues on windows 7 64 bit.
On some web sites, they suggest to install eclipse 64 bit and jdk 64 bit and also jdk 32 bit together because eclipse supports 32 bit windows. They say it works so but i couldn't.
Thank you...

Comment: @paradise: you need both the 64-bits version of eclipse *and* the 64-bits version of the JVM to make this work.

Comment: nice torn egdes. Use a program (if so, which?) or manual (if so, how?)

Comment: @basszero: FastStone Capture (http://superuser.com/questions/38487/recommendations-for-screen-capture-tool-that-retains-menus-and-mouse-pointer). It rocks and allows for the "ultimate combo": http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775

Answer (score 2):

From a new Windows 7 installation, you should:

- Install `Java SE 6 Update 35 jdk-6u35-windows-x64.exe` then download and unzip `eclipse-SDK-3.72-win32-x86_64`.
- If you are going to install Android tools, be sure to set your environment variable for `JAVA_HOME` to the JRE directory (C:\Program Files\Java\jre6) not the JDK. You do this from Control Panel Home||Advanced system settings...System Properties|Advanced|Environment Variables.

Answer (score 2):

```
I managed to solve this issue, by :
->ensuring that i have a JRE installed
->Opened eclipse.ini with notepad or notepad++(or any note editor)
->type the following and save

-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\javaw.exe


it worked for me, hope it does for you too!!
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find Eclipse runs better on JDK 1.5, particularly if you are not using the very latest versions of the 64-bit JDK and Eclipse Galileo.

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact version of your Eclipse and JDK? See also [this page](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project-plan.php?projectid=eclipse#target_environments) for the supported target environments.

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded eclipse for Windows 7, installed "eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32-x86_64.zip" from eclipse.org/downloads and got an error when tried to install it on th machine. Then I found JAVA is not installed on my m/c So I downloaded the suitable version for this O.S. and issue is resolved.

**So check whether JAVA is installed on your m/c first... then try to install eclipse**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Java was installed first (look JDK & JRE at Java Folder on :\Program Files and or Program Files (x86). If not yet, you can download it from Java official page. Visit java.sun.com (now redirect to Oracle.com).  If Java already installed on your system, please put your Eclipse folder on your system root (where Windows folder exist). Example C:\Eclipse.
Last, install necessarily SDK (ex: Android, or Blackberry).

At glance:
- Install Java SE (Standard Edition) SDK 6 (JDK 1.6), better install both 64 and 32 if you are running on Win 7 (64 Edition)
- Put your Eclipse folder on system root, eg: C:\Eclipse
- Run your Eclipse.exe

If Eclipse window not appear yet, please get another Eclipse package. The package may corrupt or have been modified.