# How do I set up Android (ADT-Plugin) for Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm setting up Eclipse for Android and when attempting to install the ADT plugin, I encounter the following error:

**Edit:** Notice the more complete error message here.

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: Android Development Tools 0.9.9.v201009221407-60953 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 0.9.9.v201009221407-60953)
>     Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 0.9.9.v201009221407-60953 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 0.9.9.v201009221407-60953) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found

I'm on Win7 x64 and using Eclipse 3.5.

What could be wrong?

EDIT:

Did I not set my Path correctly? This is what the relevant part looks like.

> Path...;C:\Users\Moshe\Development\android-sdk-windows\tools

Do I need to reboot after modifying the path?

**EDIT:**

I am looking to install this package:

> org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0

Comment: did you put SDK Location in Eclipse->Prefernces->Android?

Comment: Android doesnt show up in the preferences window yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you go through this [Installing the ADT Plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing1.2.3.4.-6.7.8.9.10.)?

1. Start Eclipse, then select Help >
   Install New Software.
2. In the Available Software dialog,
   click Add....1.
3. In the Add Site dialog that appears,
   enter a name for the remote site
   (for example, "Android Plugin") in
   the "Name" field.2.
4. In the "Location" field, enter this
   URL:
   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
5. Note: If you have trouble acquiring
   the plugin, you can try using "http"
   in the URL, instead of "https" (https
   is preferred for security reasons).4.
6. Click OK.
7. Back in the Available Software view,
   you should now see "Developer Tools"
   added to the list.6.
8. Select the checkbox next to
   Developer Tools, which will
   automatically select the nested
   tools Android DDMS and Android
   Development Tools.7.
9. Click Next.8.
10. In the resulting Install Details
     dialog, the Android DDMS and
     Android Development Tools features
     are listed.9.
11. Click Next to read and accept the
     license agreement and install any
     dependencies, then click Finish.
     Restart Eclipse.10.

This problem is caused because you have some plugins missing that are required by android tools. You can fix this by either installing a version of Eclipse which comes bundled with a lot of the eclipse plugins, or by tracking down the plugins yourself.

To do this, run eclipse, and go to Help->Install New software.  Attempt to install the Android SDk, and you will be informed of what is missing, e.g:

***Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 0.9.6.v201002051504-24846 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 0.9.6.v201002051504-24846) requires ***'org.eclipse.gef 0.0.0' but it could not be found

So we need to install org.eclipse.gef .  A quick Google for org.eclipse.gef, gives us www.eclipse.org/gef
Follow the link, and on the left hand side you will see a link for "Update Manger", follow that link...

You then have a list of URI's similar to the one for the Android plugin.  Copy the one ending in "releases"( http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases/ if you can't be bothered ), and go back to eclipse.  Paste this URI into the "Work with" box, as you did with the Android plugin, and install the components that come up.

Continue to do this until all of the Android dependencies are met, and the Android plugin will install.  You will need to locate the correct locations for each of the required dependencies.

Comment: I get up to `9.Click Next.8.` Then it says gives me the error I posted.

Comment: I edited so you have more details. Let me know if that helps you help me.

Comment: I downloaded and extracted the SDK and added the classpath. I got up to step 4 on the main quick start page, installing ADT.

Comment: use the tool that is in the downloaded folder to install the sdk, you do not need to set any classpath, the installation tool does everything for you, have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809536/setting-up-eclipse-for-android-sdk

Comment: There's no "3" in the URL "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/". Please fix the typo. :)

Comment: @Sufian Thank you for update, edited with new link https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Answer (score 4):

Download and use "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" 
it has all necessory dependents required by ADT Plugin.

Following setupworked for me
OS : win 7 64 bit
Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers : version 3.7 (32 bit)
ADT Plugin : Version 12.0.0

Answer (score 3):

If you use Eclipse Galileo then add http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo to the list of update sites. Eclipse will download most of the dependencies during ADT Plugin installation.

Answer (score 2):

Download the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers from http://eclipse.org/downloads/, and you should have no problems at all.

Comment: The Android developer seem to be giving bad advice: "For Eclipse 3.5 or newer, the "Eclipse Classic" version is recommended. Otherwise, a Java or RCP version of Eclipse is recommended."  I think your suggestion is much better - the Java edition has all the dependencies already included (EMF and GEF) and is a smaller download to boot (no source code).

Comment: yes I remember I spent all day installing and installing on my Linux Kubuntu, until I tried that solution. thank you ;)

Answer (score 2):

In addition, we should add

- -http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emft/updates/
- -http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases/

at the Eclipse Available Software repositories, in order to install the Android toolchain.

Answer (score 2):

there is a last checkbox, 'contact all update site' make sure to check that one as well before you click on next.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem with a bare new Eclipse installation. Make sure that "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" is checked when installing Developer Tools!

Comment: I spent several hours facing this problem, then once I "checked" the checkbox, it just worked.. I wish that checkbox was checked by default..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

```
Window -> Preferences -> Install/Updates -> Available Software Sites
```

Look for lines with location

```
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/*version_name*
```

then check the one with the latest *version_name*.

Also, as other answered, check the *"Contact all update sites during install to find required software"* in the *"install new software..."* dialog.
Dependencies will be installed automatically when you try to install ADT.

I post this here because I had a similar situation today. For some reason, an upgrade of kubuntu upgraded eclipse to *indigo* unchecking the respective line for *helios* in the available software sites.
*indigo* update site has dependencies issues ATTOW, so checking *helios* one again did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy and simple to install the dependency **org.eclipse.wst.xml.core 0.0.0** by taking the following steps:

- Go to help
- Install New Software: Add Name: Indigo Location: "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo"
- Select 'WST Server Adapters' under ***'Web, XML, Java,..."*** (last name in list)
- Accept licensing agreement
- Restart Eclipse
- Resume procedure to install ADT

Hope it works for you too

Answer (score 0):

Turn off virus scanners and Windows Firewall and try again. It worked for me.