# Android Emulator does not work with KVM

Tags: android, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android emulator is based on QEMU. Can I use KVM with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598942/android-emulator-is-based-on-qemu-can-i-use-kvm-with-it)

I am programing an Android app and I would like to test my app on a tablet. But I don't have a tablet and I am not going to buy one. That's why I need a good emulator, but the "old" emulator is really slow on my machine, so I need either a good Android-x86 support or the KVM support from the Android emulator.

Problem is: KVM does not work and the x86 images are good in speed, but poor in screen rotation support (what really bugs me, because that's what I need). My machine is:

Hardware:

- AMD Phenom II 1055T, virtualization is enabled
- Radeon HD5750 (maybe an OpenGL issue?)

Software:

- Arch Linux
- qemu-kvm installed (and I can run a virtual machine with kvm enabled)
- Android SDK r20 installed
- Android SDK platform tools r14 installed
- Intel x86 Atom Image installed (API 15 and 16, both don't work)
- proprietary fglrx drivers installed and working

According to https://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html , this setup should work, but when I try to launch the emulator from command line, like the link suggest, I get a black window and nothing happens (I waited about 30 minutes). I start the emulator with:

```
emulator -verbose -avd Nexus7KVM -qemu -m 1024 -enable-kvm
```

When I change `-enable-kvm` to `-disable-kvm`, the emulator starts, but it is as slow as before (of course). The output is on pastebin: [Link](http://pastebin.com/gvQfpAny).

Any suggestions are appreciated. Even if you say "Ubuntu 12.04 or whatever works for me"... I am really thinking about installing a more known Linux distribution just to get the emulator working.

Edit:
I added the `-show-kernel` flag, here is the output on pastebin: [Link](http://pastebin.com/jtkXFdmx)

I tried the emulator on my fresh installed Debian system. Same behaviour.
Issue on AOSP: [Link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=33483).

Comment: I found that topic earlier. It's was posted before Intel released a x86 Android Image with official KVM support.