# Eclipse Java: Template for the 'create field' quick fix suggestion?

Tags: java, eclipse, templates

In constructors I very often assign to a non-existing field and choose Ctrl+1 "Create field 'memberField' in type 'CurrentType'".

The problem is that I want the field to be final by default, which it isn't. Is there a template for this quick fix somewhere? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't see any obvious way to do that through code template, perhaps because this is not the Java language default.
While there are [blog posts](http://javarizon.wordpress.com/2010/06/26/why-every-java-field-should-have-been-final-by-default/) [out there](http://charsequence.blogspot.com/2010/02/data-immutability-in-java.html) advocating for Data immutability by default, this is not the default style in use, as in has been [previously debated in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137868/using-final-modifier-whenever-applicable-in-java) (or in [many other SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+final))

However, you can modify the Cleanup process (occurring on each save if you want):

```
Java > Code Style > CleanUp > Code Style
```

and **`select Use modifier 'final' where possible`**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I waited a while to see if any other alternatives would show up but this one does the job well. As a side note I realized that you can use Ctrl+1 'assign to new field' for the constructor parameter and the assignment as well as the final field declaration will be generated. This works well with direct assignments.

Comment: @VonC - Which SW did you use in order to take the screen shot?

Comment: @superjos: http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm (not free, but worth every penny)

Answer (score 2):

You can ask eclipse to put `final` on save operation. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743973/final-in-method-parameter-in-eclipse/3744004#3744004) may help.