# Final in method parameter in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, final

When I try to put final in method parameter eclipse doesn't help. Any idea how to get this to work?

[image: final in method parameter]

Comment: `inal`? sometimes typing is faster than auto completion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.

The closest thing to this is to set a "save action" which will automatically add final modifiers to method parameters when you save the file.

```
Preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions
```

Comment: Excellent feature. This is more useful than content assist.

Answer (score 4):

This probably will be as close as you can get to it. It would be a lot of work to do this for every keyword, but since there is only so many of them it's possible. You could probably take it a step further and just write a template for your methods.

1. Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates
2. New > Name (alias)
3. Pattern: "final "

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are complaining about the Eclipse Java editor's completion behavior, I don't think there's anything you can do about it.

If it really worries you, create a bug report on the relevant Eclipse component.  Better still, create and submit a patch that fixes the problem.

**EDIT**

I had a trawl through the Eclipse JDT open bugs/issues, and there are various issues related to `final` in various contexts, though not specifically this one (as far as I can see).  It is also worth noting that there are a LOT of open JDT issues ... so an issue with a viable patch is much more likely to receive attention.

Comment: It should worry everyone, shdn't it? But the answer fahd is pretty cool!

Comment: @fastcodejava - *"It should worry everyone, shdn't it?"* - Why?  This is clearly little more than a minor inconvenience.  *"But the answer fahd is pretty cool!"* - That depends if you like the idea of the editor rewriting your code without giving you a chance to see what it has just done.  I personally dislike that kind of thing.

Comment: @javaguy - that's your opinion.  In my opinion (and I guess the JDT developers) it is a minor issue.  If you really want/need this functionality, develop a patch and submit it.

Answer (score 0):

Java makes a copy of the parameters, the final parameter in this case doesn't do anything, it doesn't help you access it through an inner/anonymous class. Is there a reason you want it?

Comment: It keeps you from accidentally re-assigning it. But in that case, I would recommend just turning on the relevant warning instead.